# Sql Azure Connection Failed

Tags: sql-server, azure

An application hosted in Azure is raising this exception when trying to open connection with Sql Database:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to transient failure.
>   If you are connecting to Sql Azure database, consider using
>   SqlAzureStrategy.

I tried to turn firewall off, but it didn't work.

I'm able to connet to sql database tthrough sql management studio, but the web app isn't.

It uses EF6 to connect with database. 
Here is the peace of code, which raise error:

```
var usuario = Db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Login == login).FirstOrDefault();
if (usuario != null && usuario.ProfissionalID.HasValue)
{
  usuario.Profissional = Db.Profissional.Where(x => x.ProfissionalID == usuario.ProfissionalID).FirstOrDefault();
}
return usuario;
```

I saw in Microsoft Article, a recomendation to use SqlAzureStrategy to try reconnect when first connection attempt fails:

```
public class DbContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
  public DbContextConfiguration()
  {
    SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient",
      () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be the solution of my problem, because when I implemented this, I got this error message:

> Maximum number of retries (1) exceeded while executing database
>   operations with 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy'.

Comment: My connection string: <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.ControleHorasCont‌​ext.csdl|res://*/Con‌​text.ControleHorasCo‌​ntext.ssdl|res://*/C‌​ontext.ControleHoras‌​Context.msl;provider‌​=System.Data.SqlClie‌​nt;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXX;initial catalog=XXX;persist security info=True;user id=XXX;password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=Entity‌​Framework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: What do you mean you tried turning the firewall off? Do you mean you added your IP address to the exceptions? Is this app running in Azure when you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is a database issue otherwise you would see a very different error which actually states the IP address is not allowed through the firewall.

Instead I would try looking at this post from [Markus Wagner](http://ritzlgrmft.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/working-with-sqlazureexecutionstrategy.html) where he talks about the **maxRetryCount** and **maxDelay** parameters. For me that would be a good starting point to ensure your code is properly engineered towards working with these classes.

Secondly a number of best practices are [published](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx#GeneralBestPractices) around working with the Azure SQL service. I would be looking to make sure you meet all of these best practices and look to tune where possible. I would be looking at:

- Minimising network latency
- Reducing network usage by introducing application level caching
- Managing the network connection, keeping it open as short as possible
- Tune your SQL
- Implement retry logic

Comment: Thanks for your help @Martyn. Following your recomendations, I could get it worked, by removing one of two database query that was executed in the same operation. I'm not sure,but this error was raising in the second query. Bouth querys were fast, but was making two connections in the Database. This is the reason of this error?

Comment: Depending on how you handled your connections it could have been @OtavioCamargo, difficult to say without seeing more code.